# How we can use magento 1.9.3 saved cc method

Tags: magento-1.9

How we can use magento default "SAVED CC" payment method,
it is not saving credit card information on my site,

Answer (score 1):

You should never use the default 'Saved CC' payment method. It is unsave to store your clients credit card data. If you store get's hacked, then all your clients creditcards are leaked. It is better use a payment service provider.

For example: 
https://www.multisafepay.com/nl_nl/ (Europe) or https://payment-services.ingenico.com/nl/nl (Europe)

Most PSP's offer free Magento 1 and 2 modules.